# Binding jQuery parameters from Angular

Tags: angular

Please forgive my inexperience here. I am a longtime object oriented developer who is new to both Angular and jQuery.  I am developing my first single place application using Angular 8.  It involves a 3rd party audio player that I purchased online - and it employs jQuery to trigger song selection, etc.  It works perfectly when I hard code the jQuery call.  But I need to bind the values sent to the audio player to whats in my data set.  Consider this colum in my NGX-DATATABLE:

```
              <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template> Track Name </ng-template>
              <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery.audio7_html5.changeMp3('/assets/songs/feelit.m4a','The Song Name','The Song Author','/assets/audio/images/p3.jpg')">
                   {{ value }}
                </a>
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>

Works fine.  But I need something like this:

<ngx-datatable-column name="Title">
              <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template> Track Name </ng-template>
              <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jQuery.audio7_html5.changeMp3('{{ row.songURL }}','{{ row.songTitle }}', '{{ row.songAuthor }}','{{ row.coverArtURL }}')">
                   {{ value }}
                </a>
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>

Is what I am trying to do possible?  Or is there a better way?  I'm very frustrated over here.  Thanks in advance for any advice or guidance you might be able to offer.
```

Comment: When I changed the onclick to (click) to bind with an Angular value ... Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 31 in [jQuery.audio7_html5.changeMp3('{{ value }}','The Song Name','The Song Author','/assets/audio/images/p3.jpg')] in ng:///DataTablesModule/DTPagingComponent.html@27:55 ("t-value="value" ngx-...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you try to implement this scenario.

**in template change, this**

```
onclick="jQuery.audio7_html5.changeMp3('{{ row.songURL }}','{{ row.songTitle }}', '{{ row.songAuthor }}','{{ row.coverArtURL }}')"
```

**to this**

```
(click)="functionFromTsFile(row)"
```

**in ts file**

```
declare var jQuery: any;   // <---- this line is very important

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
})
export class SomeComponent {
   // some code ......

   functionFromTsFile(row: {
      songURL: string;
      songTitle: string; 
      songAuthor: string; 
      coverArtURL: string
    }) {
       jQuery.audio7_html5.changeMp3(row.songURL, row.songTitle, row.songAuthor, row.coverArtURL);
   }

}
```

Comment: Ashot - You nailed it right on the head.  Your recommendation worked for me perfectly. Thank you for saving me days of trial and error.  Thank you my friend.

Comment: Glad to help you @GordonHumphrey!